# Can high volume portal user profile be got using UserInfo.getProfileId in Trigger context

Tags: apex, trigger, profile, user, high-volume-portal

A trigger on a custom object runs when a portal user does some operation.
This trigger calls a public static method from a public apex class which does not have with sharing defined.
I need to access high volume portal users profile inside static method in class which is used from Trigger. Will i get portal user profile always ? I am getting inconsistent results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition a HVCP user doesn't have any sharing via Roles. They get their access to their account and related records through [implicit sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_across_objects.htm&type=5). Other records they get access to will be via sharing groups. The implicit sharing is likely what's causing the inconsistent results.